# javascript compare array of objects by key

Tags: javascript, object

I want to match id and parentId if match then add in child

ex

```js
let menuItems = [
  {
        "id": "menu-0",
        "title": "Home",
        "parentId": "menu-1",
        "childCount": 0
    },
     {
        "id": "menu-1",
        "title": "About",
        "parentId": null,
        "childCount": 2
    },
     {
        "id": "menu-3",
        "title": "About Sub1",
        "parentId": "menu-1",
        "childCount": 2
    },
     {
        "id": "menu-5",
        "title": "About Sub2",
        "parentId": "menu-1",
        "childCount": 0
    },
     {
        "id": "menu-4",
        "title": "About Sub1 sub1",
        "parentId": "menu-3",
        "childCount": 0
    },
     {
        "id": "menu-6",
        "title": "Contact",
        "parentId": null,
        "childCount": 2
    }
]
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>About
     <ul>
         <li>
            About Sub1
         </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
            Contact
 </li>
</ul>
```

```
data[i].id == data[i].parentId
```

but return `false`

Comment: Please post your desired outcome and what you have already tried. It is hard to answer a question that of which has no clear outcome.

Comment: how to comparing different object like [{id:1,parentId:null },{id:2,parentId:1 }] want first object id and second object parentId

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the same object's id and parentId, that's why it always returns false. I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve but if you want to calculate childCount you could do something like this:

```
menuItems.forEach( parent => parent.childCount = menuItems.filter( child => parent.id === child.parentId).length);
```

Comment: so how to comparing different object like [{id:1,parentId:null },{id:2,parentId:1 }]  want first object id and second object parentId

Comment: You could also do two different loops on the same array, for( let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) { for( let j= 0; j < menuItems.length; j++) { if(menuItems[i].id === menuItems[j].parentId) { //do stuff } }}

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if(data[i].id == data[j].parentId){
                        console.log(data[i]);
                    }
            }
        }{id: "menu-1", title: "About", parentId: null, childCount: 2}
 {id: "menu-1", title: "About", parentId: null, childCount: 2}
 {id: "menu-3", title: "About Sub1", parentId: "menu-1", childCount: 2} wrong value

Comment: Glad I helped! if you thinks it's the correct answer please mark it as so ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here{ for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if(data[i].id == data[j].parentId){
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
        }
    }

output
{id: "menu-1", title: "About", parentId: null, childCount: 2}
 {id: "menu-1", title: "About", parentId: null, childCount: 2}
 {id: "menu-3", title: "About Sub1", parentId: "menu-1", childCount: 2}
```

}